# UICollectionView items are hidden below the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've created a collectionView which shows 10 items.

In iPhone 4" or < screen it does now show some items after scrolling 1 or 2 items.

Like for UIScrollView we set contentSize to show the contents below the screen. So we can scroll the content.

But in UICollectionView its now showing the last item(10th) for iPhone 4" and last two items(9th and 10th) for iPhone 3.5" screen.

I tried setting contentSize for collection view still no luck.

UITableView works perfectly, but i wanted the stretchy effect of collectionView so using it.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake( 0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 64 );

CNStretchyCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [ [ CNStretchyCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc ] init ];

UICollectionView* collectionView = [ [ UICollectionView alloc ] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:layout ];

[ layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width - 15, CELL_HEIGHT) ];

// Register the cell
[ collectionView registerClass:[ TKCollectionViewCell class ] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

[ collectionView setContentInset:layout.bufferedContentInsets ];


// Set the delegate for the collection view

[ collectionView setDelegate:self ];
[ collectionView setDataSource:self ];
[ collectionView setClipsToBounds:YES];


// Customize the appearance of the collection view
[ collectionView setBackgroundColor:LIGHT_GRAY_COLOR ];

[ collectionView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault ];

[ collectionView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES ];

[ self.view addSubview:collectionView ];
```

Comment: did you try to mofify contensize for layout. just like `layout.contentsize`? was there anything change?

Comment: no layout.contentSize is not there. There is a method in CNStretchyCollectionViewFlowLayout
    - (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
    {
  CGSize contentSize = [super collectionViewContentSize];
  
 return contentSize;
    }

Comment: I can see all items if i reduce my itemSize in 4" screen but in 3.5" its not seen